# WebSphere 9 : JAX-WS WebService Unable to Deploy

Tags: java, websphere, jax-ws, java-ee-7, websphere-8

My Project recently decided to move to WebSphere 9 from WAS 8.5.5.6 and as part of this upgrade, we had JAX-WS services that needs to work as-is.

A little background on services - We had been using SUN Reference Implementation (sun-jaxws.xml) which was easier to configure, however with WAS upgrade sun-jaxws.xml file is now completely ignored along with the web.xml entries we had.

Steps we took to migrate from 8.5.5.6 to 9:

1. Migrated web.xml spec to 3.1 and removed all entries which were specific to Sun reference implementation (e.g. WSServletContextListener, or WSServlet and all the <servlet> and <servlet-mapping> entries)
2. Each of our services by default had @WebService annotation so we didn't had to make any changes there.
3. All our EJB's were modified from EJB 3.1 to EJB 3.2 - Again, since all of our code was already using Java based annotations, we didn't had to make any changes (just updated ejb-jar.xml to 3.2)

After doing the changes, we deployed the application and initially I got one common error for most of the web services:

> JAX-WS Service Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: A WSDL Definition could not be generated for the implementation class: gov.state.ServiceImpl
>       at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(WASWSDLGenerator.java:257)

After getting the above error, I added **wsdlLocation** attribute on my web service implementation class as below:

```
@javax.jws.WebService(endpointInterface = "gov.state.ServiceIntegrationBean",
                  targetNamespace = "http://st.services.state.gov", 
                  serviceName = "ServiceIntegrationService", 
                  portName = "ServiceIntegration",
                  wsdlLocation="wsdl/ServiceIntegration/ServiceIntegration.wsdl")
```

The Error went away, server started all well - But my WSDL is not hitting the URL I configured..

Does anyone have any idea on what else I could be doing wrong.. or perhaps, if anyone knows how to re-use Sun Reference Implementation of JAX-WS WebServices on WebSphere 9?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: putting the url in the wsdl and expecting the runtime to honor that isn't the way it works.  the actual url comes from a rather involved set of rules in jsr224.  The context root of the app and the servlet mapping of the webservice have precedence, after that some rules based on the annotation kick in.  But a close look at Systemout.log will probably reveal where it is.  A look at the "services" tab in the admin console might also be informative.

Comment: I do not have any servlet mapping in web.xml for my web service.. Also, when I look at services tab, it shows my service as Service Provider, but when I try to click on "Start Listener", it says the module does not have any web service! Also, I haven't created a wsdl, it is supposed to be dynamically created by WAS runtime based on my annotations provided above.. What else is missing?

Comment: Ok, if there is no wsdl packaged in the app, then the wsdllocation attribute should not be present.  As far as I know, WebSphere has never honored sun-jaxws.xml, so I'm wondering if some third party runtime jars (jax-ws, jaxb) might have been included with your application or supplied as shared libs in your 8.5.5.x installation.   If so, you might need to disable the WebSphere implementation.  ( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html )

Comment: If that's not it, then once the wsdllocation attribute is removed, turn on trace of com.ibm.ws.websvcs.*=all and look upstream of the "wsdl could not be generated" error in trace.log for "wsgen".  That's the call to the JDK tool that produces the wsdl.  Hopefully it emitted some useful error message that explains why it could not produce the wsdl.